# ColdFusion Function Error (cfc)

Tags: coldfusion-10, cfc

I am having a little problem with a cfc that is not supposed to return any thing.  Its only function is to insert information into a couple database tables.  I am getting a generic message stating "The value returned from the PutLocSalesRegisterInfo function is not of type boolean.".  Is there anyone who have had a similar problem and fixed it somehow?  Here is my function below.

```
<cffunction name="PutLocSalesRegisterInfo" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean">
    <cfargument name="OrgID"                        required="yes" type="any">
    <cfargument name="LocID"                        required="yes" type="any">
    <cfargument name="RegNum"                       required="yes" type="any">
    <cfargument name="userID"                       required="yes" type="any">
    <cfargument name="firstName"                    required="yes" type="any" default="">
    <cfargument name="LastName"                     required="yes" type="any" default="">
    <cfargument name="effectiveDate"                required="yes" type="any" default="">
    <cfargument name="VisaAmount"                   required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="VisaCount"                    required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="discoverCount"                required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="discoverAmount"               required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="MasterCardCount"              required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="MasterCardAmount"             required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="debitCount"                   required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="debitAmount"                  required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="AmericanExpressCount"         required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="AmericanExpressAmount"        required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="ccCountTotal"                 required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="ccAmtTotal"                   required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="CheckCount"                   required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="CheckAmount"                  required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="CreditIssuedCount"            required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="CreditIssuedAmount"           required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="eChecksCount"                 required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="eChecksAmount"                required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="CreditRedeemedCount"          required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="CreditRedeemedAmount"         required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="GiftCertIssuedCount"          required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="GiftCertIssuedAmount"         required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="GiftCardIssuedCount"          required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="GiftCardIssuedAmount"         required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="GiftCertRedeemedCount"        required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="GiftCertRedeemedAmount"       required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="GiftCardRedeemedCount"        required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="GiftCardRedeemedAmount"       required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="VouchersCount"                required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="VouchersAmount"               required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="cashDonationsCount"           required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="cashDonationsAmount"          required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="ChangeRndUpCount"             required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <cfargument name="ChangeRndUpAmount"            required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="ExpectedCashfromRegister"     required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="ExpectedCashFromDrawer"       required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="CashTotal"                    required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="CashTotalAmountEntered"       required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="Cashadjust"                   required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="ActualCashMinusChangeStock"   required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="transactions"                 required="no" type="any" default="0">
    <!--- <cfargument name="totalSalesandTax"           required="no" type="any" default="0.00"/> --->
    <cfargument name="salesTaxadjustment"           required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="salesTax"                     required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="totalSales"                   required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="taxExemptSales"               required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <!--- <cfargument name="commercialGoods"                required="no" type="any" default="0.00"/> --->
    <cfargument name="changeStock"                  required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
    <cfargument name="overshort"                    required="no" type="any" default="0.00">
            <!--- local empty variables --->
            <cfset var PutRegSalesInfo ="">
            <cfset var PutRegisterBalanceDetail ="">
            <cfset var PutSalesCategories ="">
            <cfset var PutCCDetail ="">
            <!--- Strip commas and dollar signs from the argument --->
            <cfset OverShort = ReplaceNoCase(ReplaceNoCase(Arguments.overshort,',','','ALL'),'$','','ALL')>
            <cfset ActualCashMinusChangeStock = ReplaceNoCase(ReplaceNoCase(Arguments.ActualCashMinusChangeStock,',','','ALL'),'$','','ALL')>
            <cfset cashTotal = ReplaceNoCase(ReplaceNoCase(Arguments.cashTotal,',','','ALL'),'$','','ALL')>
            <cfset totalSales = ReplaceNoCase(ReplaceNoCase(Arguments.totalSales,',','','ALL'),'$','','ALL')>
            <cfset ExpectedCashFromDrawer = ReplaceNoCase(ReplaceNoCase(Arguments.ExpectedCashFromDrawer,',','','ALL'),'$','','ALL')>

                <cftry>
                    <cftransaction>
                        <cfquery name="PutRegSalesInfo" datasource="#application.dsn.name#">
                            INSERT INTO Data_Org_Location_Register_Totals
                               (
                               nOrganizationID
                               ,nLocationID
                               ,nRegisterNumber
                               ,cCashierFirstName
                               ,cCashierLastName
                               ,dTotalActualCash
                               ,dTotalActualCashLessChangeStock
                               ,nCountCreditCardTransactions
                               ,dTotalCreditCards
                               ,nCountChecks
                               ,dTotalChecks
                               ,nCountEChecks
                               ,dTotalEChecks
                               ,nCountCreditIssued
                               ,dTotalCreditIssued
                               ,nCountCreditRedeemed
                               ,dTotalCreditRedeemed
                               ,nCountGiftCertIssued
                               ,dTotalGiftCertIssued
                               ,nCountGiftCertRedeemed
                               ,dTotalGiftCertRedeemed
                               ,nCountGiftCardIssued
                               ,dTotalGiftCardIssued
                               ,nCountGiftCardRedeemed
                               ,dTotalGiftCardRedeemed
                               ,nCountVouchers
                               ,dTotalVouchers
                               ,nCountCashDonations
                               ,dTotalCashDonations
                               ,dTotalTaxExemptSales
                               ,nCountTransactions
                               ,dTotalSales
                               ,dSalesTax
                               ,dSalesTaxAdjustment
                               ,tEffectiveDate
                               ,nAvailable
                               ,tCreationDate
                               ,nActive
                               ,tLastUpdate
                               ,cChangedBy
                               )
                             VALUES(
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.OrgID#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.LocID#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.RegNum#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Arguments.firstName#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Arguments.LastName#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(cashTotal)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(ActualCashMinusChangeStock)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.ccCountTotal#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.ccAmtTotal)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.CheckCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.CheckAmount)#">,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.eChecksCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.eChecksAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.CreditIssuedCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.CreditIssuedAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.CreditRedeemedCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.CreditRedeemedAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.GiftCertIssuedCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.GiftCertIssuedAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.GiftCertRedeemedCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.GiftCertRedeemedAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.GiftCardIssuedCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.GiftCardIssuedAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.GiftCardRedeemedCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.GiftCardRedeemedAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.VouchersCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.VouchersAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.CashDonationsCount#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.CashDonationsAmount)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.taxExemptSales)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.Transactions#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(totalSales)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.salesTax)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.salesTaxadjustment)#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#DateFormat(CreateODBCDateTime(Arguments.effectiveDate), 'dd/mm/yyyy')#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(1)#"/>,
                               GetDate(),
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(1)#"/>,
                               GetDate(),
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.userID#"/>
                               )
                              SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS New_PutRegSalesInfo_ID
                        </cfquery>

                    <!--- Create random unique Ref number (dont know why this is needed if there is a PK)--->
                        <cfset local.random_part = Randomize(PutRegSalesInfo.New_PutRegSalesInfo_ID, "SHA1PRNG")>
                        <cfset local.UserRefToHash = Now() & "ref" & PutRegSalesInfo.New_PutRegSalesInfo_ID & ":" & local.random_part>
                        <cfset local.NewSalesInfoRefID = Hash(local.UserRefToHash, 'sha-256', 'iso-8859-1')>

                        <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn.name#" name="UpdateRegisterTotalsRef">
                            update  Data_Org_Location_Register_Totals
                            set     cRegisterTotalsRefID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#local.NewSalesInfoRefID#"/>
                            where   nID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#PutRegSalesInfo.New_PutRegSalesInfo_ID#"/>
                        </cfquery>

                        <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn.name#" name="PutRegisterBalanceDetail">
                            Insert into Data_Org_Location_Register_BalanceDetail (
                                nRegisterTotalsID,
                                nOrganizationID,
                                nLocationID,
                                dExpectedCashFromRegister,
                                dCashAdjustments,
                                dAdjustedExpectedCashFromRegister,
                                dChangeStock,
                                dOverShort,
                                tCreationDate,
                                nActive,
                                tLastUpdate,
                                cChangedBy
                                )
                            values (
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#PutRegSalesInfo.New_PutRegSalesInfo_ID#"/>,
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.OrgID#"/>,
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.LocID#"/>,
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.ExpectedCashFromRegister)#"/>,
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#Arguments.CashAdjust#"/>,
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(ExpectedCashFromDrawer)#"/>,
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.ChangeStock)#"/>,
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(OverShort)#"/>,
                                GetDate(),
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(1)#"/>,
                                GetDate(),
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.UserID#"/>
                        )
                    </cfquery>
                    <!--- Get the number of CategoryIDs from the list then loop that many times--->
                     <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ListLen(Arguments.CategoryList)#"><!--- loop through the category form fields --->

                        <cfquery name="PutSalesCategories" datasource="#application.dsn.name#">
                            INSERT INTO Data_Org_Location_Register_CategorySales
                               (nOrganizationID
                               ,nLocationID
                               ,nRegisterTotalsID
                               ,nOrgCategoryID
                               ,nCount
                               ,dAmount
                               ,dAdjustment
                               ,dTotal
                               ,nAvailable
                               ,tCreationDate
                               ,nActive
                               ,tLastUpdate
                               ,cChangedBy
                               )
                            VALUES(
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.OrgID#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.LocID#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#PutRegSalesInfo.New_PutRegSalesInfo_ID#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.categoryID[i]#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.categoryCount[i]#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.Amount[i])#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Arguments.Adjustment[i]#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.total[i])#"/>,
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(1)#"/>,
                               GetDate(),
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(1)#"/>,
                               GetDate(),
                               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_interger" value="#Arguments.UserID#"/>
                               )
                        </cfquery>
                        <cfset i =  i + 1>
                    </cfloop>
                    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn.name#" name="PutCCDetail">
                        INSERT INTO Data_Org_Location_Register_CreditCardDetail
                           (
                           nRegisterTotalsID
                           ,nOrganizationID
                           ,nLocationID
                           ,nCountVisa
                           ,dTotalVisa
                           ,nCountMasterCard
                           ,dTotalMasterCard
                           ,nCountAmericanExpress
                           ,dTotalAmericanExpress
                           ,nCountDiscover
                           ,dTotalDiscover
                           ,nCountDebit
                           ,dTotalDebit
                           ,nAvailable
                           ,tCreationDate
                           ,nActive
                           ,tLastUpdate
                           ,cChangedBy
                           )
                        VALUES(
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#PutRegSalesInfo.New_PutRegSalesInfo_ID#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.OrgID#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.LocID#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.VisaCount#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.VisaAmount)#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.MasterCardCount#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.MasterCardAmount)#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.AmericanExpressCount#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.AmericanExpressAmount)#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.DiscoverCount#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.DiscoverAmount)#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.DebitCount#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#DecimalFormat(Arguments.DebitAmount)#"/>,
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(1)#"/>,
                            GetDate(),
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(1)#"/>,
                            GetDate(),
                            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_interger" value="#Arguments.UserID#"/>
                           )
                    </cfquery>
            </cftransaction>
        <cfreturn true>
        <cfcatch>
            <cfinvoke method="errorHandler" argumentcollection="#ARGUMENTS#" />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Well the function signature says it is supposed to return something: `returntype="boolean"` .  If it is not supposed to return anything, use `returnType="void".`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your catch block is executed, there would be no return.
Maybe you want to return false as the last line of your cfcatch.
Otherwise put the cfreturn true as the last line of the function.
Can you verify that catch block is not being executed?

Comment: The catch block is being executed which basicly gives me the CFC error Dump in my email.  When I comment out the catch block I am seeing the line of code that is having the error as well.  Thank you for that.  However, the loop is now causing an issue where the number in the value of "i" is not dynamically placed in its place.  For example: if it loops three times  "i" should be 1 on the first loop, 2 on the second loop, and 3 on the last loop.

Comment: You should var scope i too.  cfset var i = 1   prior to the loop.

Comment: Even after adding the <cfset var = 1> statement prior to the loop, I still get "categoryID is undefined".  And that is correct. however it should be categoryID1.

Comment: That is too much code for one function. I do not have time to review all of that code, but from what I can see the error message is accurate. There is no `CategoryID` variable in the arguments scope, same with a few of the other variables. Also, the code is referencing the non-existent variables as arrays, but it is difficult to tell what type of variables you are working with as everything is type "any".  Break it into smaller pieces. Test one piece at a time.  Side note, this is a totally different question than what was asked. Consider opening a new thread, and include any errors.